# Can't do a mathematical computation using Pandas based on whether keywords do not exists in a sentence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm checking to see if a couple of words DO NOT exist in a column B and if they don't, to take an integer in column A and create a column C in which the number is negative by multiplying it by -1. If the word exists, it should remain as is.

I've run into 2 problems: 1) I can't seem to check for more than 1 word; 2) I'm getting a type error.

Here is the df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10, 21, 13, 22],
                   "B": ["Shares Rise on Jobs News", 
                         "Outflows on bad projections", 
                         "Rebounds on Bounce", 
                         "Slides on negative assumption"]})
```

Check if word exists:

```
df["C"] = \
df["B"].map(lambda x: "Negative" if "Rise" not in x else "Positive")
```

The output as expected is:

[image]

But if I add another word to look for, it breaks by returning wrong output.

```
df["C"] = \
df["B"].map(lambda x: "Negative" if "Rise" or "Rebounds" not in x else "Positive")
```

[image]

Dealing with the second part of the problem, I tweak the code to turn the numbers negative if they do not have keywords:

```
df["C"] = \
df["B"].map(lambda x: df["A"](-1) if "Rise" not in x else df["A"])
```

I get "TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `np.where` + `contains`

```
df['Out'] = np.where(df.B.str.contains('Rise|Rebounds', case=False), 'Pos', 'Nag')
df
Out[11]: 
    A                              B  Out
0  10       Shares Rise on Jobs News  Pos
1  21    Outflows on bad projections  Nag
2  13             Rebounds on Bounce  Pos
3  22  Slides on negative assumption  Nag
```

Comment: Ah. You beat me to it. I had the same solution. +1.

Comment: that works for the first part. what about the second part. I tried replacing Neg and Pos with -1 and 1 and multiply by df["A] but i get that series is not subscriptable

Comment: I think this worked: ```df['C'] = np.where(df["B"].str.contains(r'Rise|Rebounds', case=False), df["A"].multiply(1), df["A"].multiply(-1))
```